# Зависание GUI при использовании QThread

Tags: c++, qt

Появилась проблема с зависанием gui. Пытался запустить в отдельном потоке:
**mainwindow.cpp**

```
   sip *mysip = new sip;
    QThread *sip_thread = new QThread(this);

    mysip->moveToThread(sip_thread);
    sip_thread->start();

    mysip->resiveSipParameters(login,pass); //передаем логин и пароль в sip.cpp для запуска авторизации
    mysip->startSip();
```

**sip.cpp**

```
sip::sip(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void sip::resiveSipParameters(QString login, QString pass)
{
    SipLogin = login;
    SipPass = pass;
    qDebug() << SipLogin;
    qDebug() << SipPass;

}

void sip::startSip()
{
    int ret = 0;
    Endpoint ep;

    try
    {
        ep.libCreate();
       // sipReady(ep);
        ret = PJ_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch (Error & err)
    {
//            std::cout << "Exception: " << err.info() << std::endl;
//            ret = 1;
    }


    // Init library
    EpConfig ep_cfg;
    ep_cfg.logConfig.level = 6;
    ep_cfg.logConfig.filename = "/home/alexey/crm/sip.log";
    ep.libInit(ep_cfg);


    // Transport
    TransportConfig tcfg;
    tcfg.port = 5060; //5080 mango
    ep.transportCreate(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, tcfg);

    // Start library
    ep.libStart();
    // std::cout << "*** PJSUA2 STARTED ***" << std::endl;


    // Add account
    AccountConfig acc_cfg;
    acc_cfg.idUri = ("sip:"+SipLogin+"@***.mangosip.ru").toStdString();
    acc_cfg.regConfig.registrarUri = "sip:***.mangosip.ru";
    acc_cfg.sipConfig.authCreds.push_back(AuthCredInfo("digest", "*", SipLogin.toStdString(), 0, SipPass.toStdString())); //подставляем полученный логин и пароль

//  std::auto_ptr<MyAccount> acc(new MyAccount);
//  acc->create(acc_cfg);
    qDebug() << SipLogin;
    qDebug() << SipPass;

    MyAccount *acc = new MyAccount;
    try
    {
        acc->create(acc_cfg);
    }
    catch(Error& err)
    {
        std::cout << "Account creation error: " << err.info() << std::endl;
    }


    // Just wait for ENTER key
    std::cout << "Press ENTER to quit..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

В итоге все равно окно `mainwindow` зависает. Нужно ли еще делать `connect` для очереди?

Answer (score 6):

Из документации на функцию `moveToThread`:

> Changes the thread affinity for this object and its children. The object cannot be moved if it has a parent. **Event processing will continue in the targetThread**.

После выполнения функции обработка событий будет осуществляться в другом потоке. Вы же используете прямой вызов функций `resiveSipParameters` и `startSip`, тем самым функции выполняются в основном GUI-потоке.

Будет правильно использовать сигналы и слоты:

```
QObject::connect(sip_thread, &QThread::started, mysip, [&login, &pass, mysip]() {
  mysip->resiveSipParameters(login, pass);
  mysip->startSip();
});
```

Comment: Добавил коннект, но результат тот же. Хотя ошибок при компиляции не выдает. https://github.com/89626906891/crm

Comment: @AlexeySmirnov, строки 989, 990 надо бы убрать.

Comment: удалил, теперь при создании объекта  mysip вылетает. "Программа неожиданно завершилась."

Comment: Еще одна проблема в том, что запускаете поток, а затем только подключаете сигнал и слот. Надо поменять местами. Если проблема будет проявляться снова, то debug в помощь.

Comment: все равно вылетает (

Comment: не могу найти ошибку. Программа вылетает при компиляции.